# In the following situation, why is there a unique class of maps inducing a homology homomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is taken from the very first page [of this](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-28821-0_8#page-1) article by Gromov.

Let $V$ be a compact manifold, $A=H_1(V,\mathbb{R})/H_1(V,\mathbb{Z})/torsion$  and $f:V\to A$ be a continuous map (it's the Abel-Jacobi map but this should not be important) inducing $f_*:H_1(V,\mathbb{Z})\to H_1(A,\mathbb{Z})$. Then the article says that any $g:V\to A$ such that $g_*=f_*$ is homotopic to $f$. Why is this so?

EDIT: Gromov says this is true because $A$, being a torus, has an abelian fundamental group and a contractible universal cover.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't follow. How does $f_*=g_*$ on homology imply that $f_*$ is trivial on homotopy? In fact, it can't be trivial, since $f_*$ is the so-called "Abel isomorphism" on homology, and since $H_1(A,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\pi_1(A)$ are isomorphic for the torus, then $f_*$ must be onto on $\pi_1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably horribly misinterpreted your question. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Perhaps something like Whitehead's theorem applies here? I think it says something about equivalent maps on homology yielding equivalent maps on homotopy under some conditions on $\pi_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $A$ is an Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\pi_1(A),1)$. By the naturality of the Hurewicz homomorphism, $f$ and $g$ also induce the same map on the first homotopy groups (the Hurewicz map is an iso for the space $A$, since $\pi_1(A)$ is already abelian). Now for maps from a connected $CW$ complex into a $K(G,1)$, every homomorphism on the level of fundamental groups is induced by a up to homotopy unique map on space level (This is for example Prop. 1B9 in Hatcher).

I admit that there are some basepoint issues that I ignored.